# How to do capture the termination of a rack app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, celluloid

I have a Sinatra app running, and there's some background threads running using Celluloid.  When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed, I want to cleanly terminate those running agents.  How do I cleanly terminate them?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, your main thread will block while Sinatra is running; once it catches SIGINT, it'll break out of its runloop, and your script will continue. So, you can have a config.ru like:

```
require './my_app'
run MyApp
Celluloid.shutdown
```

`run` is going to block until the server is terminated, at which point Celluloid should start its shutdown mechanism.

However, that said, it's worth noting that Celluloid will invoke `#shutdown` automatically via an `at_exit` block. (https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/blob/master/lib/celluloid.rb#L138-L154), and Celluloid already [provides a mechanism for running code when an actor exits](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/wiki/Finalizers), so if you've defined finalizers for your actors, they should shut down cleanly without you having to do anything special WRT Sinatra.

Comment: I have tried the `finalizer`.  That didn't seem to invoke the method I specified.  I am not sure why.
Putting `Celluloid.shutdown` after `run MyApp` doesn't seem to do the job either.  It doesn't look like `rackup` blocks at `run MyApp`, rather it just continues forward.